# Assertion for http header

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, should.js

Im doing some Unit testing to node application and I check for http response. currnlty I want to test also the **http.header** response for key and value which I send,what am I doing wrong ?

```
res.header.should.have.property['prop1'];
```

1. Assume that I've prop1, how should I do that ?
2. in addition how to assert to the value of prop1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like

```
res.header.prop1.should.equal('propValue');
```

This answer both...

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `property`, not indexing into it:

```
res.header.should.have.property('prop1');
```

You can simultaneously check the value by passing it as a second argument:

```
res.header.should.have.property('prop1', 'propValue');
```